# Functions is the class ignores inputs

Tags: python, function, class, python-3.9

I've tried changing around the "if" statements and using else instead of "elif" but when using the Change function it ignores "n" or "N" inputs.

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text_speed = 1
        self.companion_name = ("")
        self.player_name = ("")

    def Change_Text_Speed(self):
        choice = int(input("Text Speed Options:\n1.5x [1] \n2x [2] \n2.5x [3] \nExit[4]"))
        if choice == 1:
            self.text_speed = (self.text_speed*1.5)
        elif choice == 2:
            self.text_speed = (self.text_speed*2)
        elif choice ==3:
            self.text_speed = (self.text_speed*2.5)
        else:
            print("No changes have been made...")

    def Change_Companion_Name(self):
        choice = str(input("Do you wish to change your companions name?[Y/N]"))
        if choice == 'y' or 'Y':
            new_name = str(input("Enter in your companions new name: "))
            self.companion_name = new_name
        elif choice == 'n' or 'N':
            print("No changes have been made...")
    
    def Change_Player_Name(self):
        choice = str(input("Do you wish to change your name?[Y/N]"))
        if choice == 'y' or 'Y':
            new_name = str(input("Enter in your new name: "))
            self.player_name = new_name
        elif choice == 'n' or 'N':
            print("No changes have been made...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a `or` in your if. I see two solution:

Use a list of YES answers:

```
def Change_Companion_Name(self):
    choice = str(input("Do you wish to change your companions name?[Y/N]"))
    if choice in ['y', 'Y']:
        new_name = str(input("Enter in your companions new name: "))
        self.companion_name = new_name
    elif choice == ['n', 'N']:
        print("No changes have been made...")
```

Use a string `upper` method to avoid multiple choices:

```
def Change_Companion_Name(self):
    choice = str(input("Do you wish to change your companions name?[Y/N]"))
    if choice.upper() == 'Y':
        new_name = str(input("Enter in your companions new name: "))
        self.companion_name = new_name
    elif choice.upper() == 'N':
        print("No changes have been made...")
```

I like the first solution, because you can use more options, like this:

```
choice = str(input("Choice Yes or No.[Y/N]"))
yes_choices = ['YES', 'Y']
if choice.upper() in yes_choices:
    print('You chose YES')
elif choice.upper() in ['NO', 'N']:
    print('You chose NO')
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def Change_Companion_Name(self):
    choice = str(input("Do you wish to change your companions name?[Y/N]"))
    if choice == 'y' or choice == 'Y':
        new_name = str(input("Enter in your companions new name: "))
        self.companion_name = new_name
    elif choice == 'n' or choice == 'N':
        print("No changes have been made...")
```

I think you should write your  if statement like above. Now you can change elif with else statement.